# How to fix a postfix myhosting config problem?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix-mta

I tried to install a postfix with a local mail config, but i have a problem with myhostname config

I need complete de install process

Running newaliases
  newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: yasser..name
  newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad           parameter value: yasser..name

I expect success install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the /etc/postfix/main.cf fixes this issue. The statements here apply to Ubuntu 20.04. The statements below use a different editor and also include before/after statements to confirm & verify you've correctly edited the main.cf:

```
# run cat|grep statement below to see what we currently have for the value we need to edit:
myusername@myusername:~$ cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep 'myhostname = '
myhostname = myusername..
# edit the /etc/postfix/main.cf file to specify the name attribute for myhostname by running the command below which uses the vi editor:    
myusername@myusername:~$ sudo vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
# run cat|grep statement below to confirm the name attribute is now specified in the /etc/postfix/main.cf:
myusername@myusername:~$ cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep 'myhostname = '
myhostname = myusername.name
```

Answer (score 4):

- Run `sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf`
- Find the line `hostname =`
- Change it:

**From:**
`myhostname = yasser..name`
**To:**
`myhostname = yasser.name` (ie. remove the extra dot)

Finally, run `sudo apt install --fix-broken`
Hope it helps.